# Generated HTML Render Issue in Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, sharepoint-2013

I am creating a html file in C# inside my SharePoint site to be stored in a document library.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine(WebUtility.HtmlDecode("<html><head></head><body><table>"));
builder.AppendLine(WebUtility.HtmlDecode("<tr><td>Time</td><td>" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "</td></tr>"));
builder.AppendLine(WebUtility.HtmlDecode("</table></body></html>"));
```

Once the html is generated, it is converted into a byte[] and then stored.

```
string myString = builder.toString();

byte[] bytesArray = new byte[myString.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(myString.ToCharArray(), 0, bytesArray, 0, bytesArray.Length);
```

The `bytesArray` is then stored in SharePoint document library.

When the created file is downloaded and viewed in Internet Explorer and Firefox, the file displays fine. But Chrome gives a symbol after each `<` and the downloaded file is displayed as below :

```
<�html><�head><�/head><�body><�table> <�tr><�td> and so on....
```

Once the file is opened using an editor and saved even without any modifications(Eg: Notepad), this render issue in Chrome goes away. Firefox and IE doesn't give this error. The only Extension showing up in my Chrome browser is GoogleDocs. Any reason why Chrome has this issue ?

Comment: What is actually strange is why there is no extra characters shown in between letters... Most likely you need to specify encoding of the document since UTF16 is not default. Alternatively you can save HTML as UTF8.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yup that was the issue. encoded to UTF8 and issues gone. Thanks !